# How do I get rid of this popup in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This little pop up comes up when I start typing new properties in objects, and seemingly all the time. It prevents me moving up/down lines because the up/down arrows scroll the contents of the box. I'm sorry to say it feels like the VSCode version of Clippy from MS Word!

[image]

I've tried the following user settings to no avail

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
  "editor.referenceInfos": false,
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

Comment: I really hate this dialog!

Comment: found an answer and it works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377965/how-to-get-rid-of-annoying-newnode-node-offset-number-popup-intellisense

Comment: accroding the discussion in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15960 and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14840, it seems the vim plugin prevent use escape key to dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Just for finality, this post does provide a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377965/how-to-get-rid-of-annoying-newnode-node-offset-number-popup-intellisense

Comment: I disabled  "Editor › Parameter Hints: Cycle" , it wont cycle and close dialog

Answer (score 14):

To disable those documentation popups, you can add this option to preferences -> settings:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

Comment: in the latest stable version as of Sep 2018, I had to use
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,

Comment: @Rose, sometimes these hints are useful though. Do you know of any way to make them hidden by default but able to reveal with a keystroke? Like intellisense for example. I can have it not bother me but it's there when I press ctrl+space.

Answer (score 8):

This one worked for me.
The popups seemed to have become more of an issue lately when they never used to hinder me before.

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false
```

Comment: OP is not talking about hover. And, it actually does not work to the problem described.

Comment: May not fix what the OP was asking about, but it fixes the issue that brought me here (function help tooltips on hover)

Answer (score 3):

That is the intellisense/refactoring support. Beyond the user settings you mentioned, it's part of the language support.

You could:

- Switch to a different "Language" setting
- Make a custom language support, that adds the intellisense features you like without the full support, then modify your vscode installation to remove the original support.
- Press the ESC key before up/down to close the popup

Comment: oh wow, I'm surprised there's no setting to turn that off :-/ well thanks for taking the time to respond. Clippy it is!