# How to get rid of annoying "newNode: node, offset: number" popup (intellisense?)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing javascript with Visual Studio Code I continuously get a useless and obtrusive popup showing some sort of irrelevant method signature

[image]

It also won't go away when typing. Even escape won't remove it but clicking in some other code usually does.

My current user config looks as follows

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/ivo/Atom/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": true,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestPath": "bin/django",
    "python.unitTest.nosetestArgs": ["test", "apps/"],
    "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": true,
    "editor.useTabStops": false,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To stop showing the annoying hint popups, open "settings.json" in VSCode: 
(File -> Preferences -> Settings).

Add the following line to the setting file (including quotes), and save it:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was going insane!

Comment: In the latest version of Visual Studio Code, this setting is named `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`

Comment: In the   File -> Preferences -> Settings   there is no  settings.json"   and no place to add that piece of code