# new window appears on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode for a long time and today when I used it I've noticed something new , new windows appear when I try to write something inside "()" like a suggestion , there is a way that I can remove it ?
thanks everyone for the help !
[the new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vZ68.png)

Comment: This thing shows you overloaded functions/methods and is usually pretty useful. You can toggle through alternative definitions and see the parameters at the top. If you want to disable it, look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246645/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-popup-in-vscode). It will however also disable other popups you might want to keep...

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I've tried to to that but still I'm getting it , It doesn't happen to me before , Its start to appear today when I worked on Maven.

Comment: This popup is most liekyl coming from the maven / java extension of vs code, maybe the extension has a setting that disables this.